# Non-transactional operations in a transactional tasklet

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am using Google App Engine SDK 1.7.3 and NDB to access the datastore.

How should I run a non-transactional tasklet from within a transactional tasklet?

The following is the first thing that comes to mind:

```
@ndb.tasklet
@ndb.non_transactional
def non_txn_method():
    ''' Run some code that does not require a transaction '''
    result = calculate_result()
    raise ndb.Return(result)

@ndb.tasklet
@ndb.transactional
def txn_method():
    ''' Run some code that requires a transaction '''
    non_txn_result = yield non_txn_method()
```

However the creator of NDB [advises](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/appengine-ndb-discuss/XBMMmA661a8/JbTDJk2_y4IJ) not to combine decorators such as is done with `@ndb.tasklet` and `@ndb.transactional` and to use the `ndb.transaction_async(callback, **ctx_options)` function instead. See [here](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=195&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) for the issue with doing this. I am therefore worried that combining the `@ndb.tasklet` and `@ndb.non_transactional` decorators could also be fragile and prone to have unexpected behaviour.

Note that `ndb.transaction_async(callback, **ctx_options)` is provided in the [NDB API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/functions) but not `ndb.non_transaction_async(callback, **ctx_options)`.

I wonder if a `ndb.non_transaction_async(callback, **ctx_options)` function needs to be exposed in the NDB API to help me robustly accomplish what I want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you file a bug for the proposed new feature in the NDB bug tracker:
http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/list

Comment: Thanks @guido, I see you are no longer working on this. http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=230&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Answer (score 2):

Note that the following decorator order works as expected (at least since 1.7.3):

```
@ndb.non_transactional
@ndb.tasklet
def non_txn_method():
  # If calling old db, need this too:
  datastore._SetConnection(None)
  # ...
```

The old db workaround is needed due to this [bug](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=232).